# setting up these mail variables in php?

Tags: php, coldfusion, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta

I am converting a coldfusion site to php and i have these mail server settings

```
 <cfapplication name="something">
<cfset mailAttributes = {
server="smtp.something.net",
username="webinquiries@something.com",
password="something.1.something",
bcc="something@something.com",
to="something@something.com",
from="webinquiries@something.com",
port="587"
}
```

I now need to convert this to php .....is there a place way to do this in PHP.

Comment: well, that really depends how those variables are used. This statement just sets variables..

Comment: yes your right but im basically looking to see if i can use set the smtp settings before I call the php mail function

Answer (score 1):

Plain PHP mail does not support external mail server with SMTP authentication.

You can do this with something like PEAR Mail or PHPMailer.